# Unable to get logic for related tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

**productskuvalue**

```
SkuId   OptionId    ProductId   valueid
1            2        264        10
```

**productoption**

```
OptionId    OptionName  
2             Size  
3            color  
4            Weight
```

**productoptionvalue**

```
ValueId OptionId ValueName  
 10        2        Small   
 11        2       Medium
```

now I want get id based names from diffrent tables. i wrote to get ids .

```
ProductSKUValues = (from resp in productSkuValueRepository.GetProductSkuValuesById(id)
select new Contracts.Models.ProductSKUValueResponse()
 {
     SkuId = resp.SkuId,
     OptionId =  resp.OptionId,
     ValueId = resp.ValueId
 }).ToList()
```

linq query

```
public IQueryable<ProductSKUValue> GetProductSkuValuesById(int Id)
{
    return DbSet.Where(a => a.ProductId == Id) ;
}
```

Would you kindly let me know how to get id based names.

expecting result:

```
         SkuId = 1,
         OptionId =  2,
         OptionName= size,
         ValueId = 10,
         valueName= Small
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use joins:

```
ProductSkuValues.Where(x => x.ProductId == id)
     .Join(ProductOptions, p => p.OptionId, po => po.OptionId, (p, po) => new 
          { 
                p.SkuId,   
                p.OptionId, 
                //p.ProductId, 
                p.ValueId, 
                po.OptionName 
          })
     .Join(ProductOptionValues, po => new { po.OptionId, po.ValueId }, pov => new { pov.OptionId, pov.ValueId }, (po, pov) => new 
         { 
                po.SkuId,   
                po.OptionId, 
                //po.ProductId,                     
                po.OptionName,
                po.ValueId, 
                pov.ValueName,
         });
```